# Need brief understanding on how eclipse autocomplete works

Tags: eclipse

Hi I am interested in understanding how eclipse autocomplete works. I want to understand how eclipse distinguishes between local and global variables in a piece of Java code. I would also like to understand how eclipse stores method signatures for an infinite number of classes and how it associates a method to a given class. And is it possible for one person to develop an autocomplete feature for a language like JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

There is already an AutoComplete feature for Javascript. You just need to let Eclipse install the appropriate extensions.

Eclipse maintains a model of your program, including the project and all the dependencies. It's big, but it's not infinite. When you hit the dot, it figures out based on the variable type what the target type can be, and then displays the relevant methods based on its internal model.

This is easy for Java because you can usually know the static type. Much harder in other languages.

The Eclipse plug-in developer's guide discusses how different things, including the internal model and auto completion works. There are extension points to implement yiur own.